# Android Broadcast receiver gives Error

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

Got another problem. Trying to use a broadcastreceiver to catch off an Alarm (alarm manager).

The following code is used:
    package com.suncco.shangxinbao.service;

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.suncco.shangxinbao.model.ScheduledSms;

public class SmsTimerService extends BroadcastReceiver {

public SmsTimerService(Context context, int timeoutInSeconds,
        ScheduledSms sms) {

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, SmsTimerService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            sms.getRequestCodeForListener(), myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5); // should be timeoutInSeconds instead of 5
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.w("Karl", "yay");
}
```

In the manifest I put this as receiver:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.suncco.shangxinbao.service.SmsTimerService"
        android:process=":remote" />
```

And I make an object of my SmsTimerService like this:

```
 SmsTimerService smsTimerService = new SmsTimerService(this,5,sms);
```

And this is the well known error...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver     
com.suncco.shangxinbao.service.SmsTimerService: java.lang.InstantiationException: 
com.suncco.shangxinbao.service.SmsTimerService
```

Comment: why you are creating an instance of SmsTimerService class bez you are doing in right why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the unable to instantiate receiver error because you don't have an empty constructor such as **SmsTimerService()**. The point is you need an empty constructor for this receiver to be created when receiving the intent. **And it's ok if you don't implement any constructor. However, if you implement a constructor with parameters, you also need to implement an empty one!**

So you can do something like this. Note that I didn't study what you actually want to do when creating intents.

```
public class SmsTimerService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private void doAction(Context context, int timeoutInSeconds, ScheduledSms sms) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, SmsTimerService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
        sms.getRequestCodeForListener(), myIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5); // should be timeoutInSeconds instead of         
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // you get to replace sms with something!
        doAction(context, 5, sms); // original u do - > new SmsTimerService(this,5,sms);
    }
}
```